# In Pyramid, how to check if view is static in NewRequest event handler?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a NewRequest event handler (subscriber) in Pyramid which looks like this:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
    request = event.request
    print('Opening DB conn')
    // Open the DB
    request.db = my_connect_to_db()
    request.add_finished_callback(close_db_connection)
```

However, I have observed that a connection to the DB is opened even if the request goes to a static asset, which is obviously unnecessary. Is there a way, from the NewRequest handler, to check if the request is bound for a static asset? I have tried comparing the view_name to my static view's name, but apparently the view_name attribute is not available at this early stage of processing the request.

If anyone has any interesting ideas about this, please let me know!

Comment: I normally don't care about this since in production I serve my static  files straight from the web server in front of the application. The request never hits the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brute force way is to compare the `request.path` variable to your static view's root, a la `request.path.startswith('/static/')`.

The method I like the best and use in my own apps is to add a property to the `request` object  called `db` that is lazily evaluated upon access. So while you may add it to the request, it doesn't do anything until it is accessed.

```
import types

def get_db_connection(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_db'):
        request._db = my_connect_to_db()
        request.add_finished_callback(close_db_connection)
    return request._db

def new_request_subscriber(event):
    request = event.request
    request.db = types.MethodType(get_db_connection, request)
```

Later in your code you can access `request.db()` to get the connection. Unfortunately it's not possible to add a property to an object at runtime (afaik), so you can't set it up so that `request.db` gives you what you want. You can get this behavior without using a subscriber by the [cookbook entry](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/authentication.html#making-a-user-object-available-as-a-request-attribute) where you subclass `Request` and add your own lazy property via Pyramid's `@reify` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

```
def _connection(request):
    print "******Create connection***"
    #conn = request.registry.dbsession()
    conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "DB_Login_Name", "DB_Password", "data_base_name")
    def cleanup(_):
        conn.close()
    request.add_finished_callback(cleanup)
    return conn

@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
    print "new_request_subscriber"
    request = event.request
    request.set_property(_connection, "db", reify = True)
```

try this one, I reference fallow web page 
http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/1.3-branch/api/request.html 
"set_property" section, it works for me.